# How can I determine which software repositories are in active use?

Tags: 11.10, update-manager, repository

I added some custom repositories sometimes ago.

How can I determine, which software I have installed is from them?

I want to delete unused repos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This thread in ubuntuforums solves the problem with synaptic:
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1685945

> Go into synaptic
>
> Select the "origin" tab in the lower left corner. There you can check
>   if you have any installed packages from a specific repository.
>
> If you find any repositories you don't need anymore you can go to
>   "software sources" on the "administration menu" and remove them from
>   there.
>
> If you don't want to remove them completely, just untick the box to
>   disable them.
>
> I would recommend you uninstall any packages from a repository you
>   want to remove since you won't receive any more updates for them.

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: understood, will do so in future.

Comment: Also, synaptic is not installed by default in 11.10.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open `Ubuntu Software Center`;
2. Pressing the drop-down arrow close to the `Installed` button on top, you can see all active repositories;
3. Select every listed repository, and check if some package is installed;
4. Click the `Edit --> Software Sources` menu;
5. Select the `Other Software` in the dialog that appears (the second one), and just remove unwanted repositories.

Comment: You actually answered another question, he asked how to see which packages are installed from certain repositories - this details how to remove a repository :)

Comment: @Caesium: from the question I understand he likes to delete unused repos.